# Strong convergence to zero

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(a^m)_{m\ge 1}$ be a sequence in a Hilbert space and also $$a^m=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^m_n e_n$$ with $a^m_n\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty}0,$ for any $n\ge 1.$

Does $a^m$ converges strongly to $0$ ?

Comment: What if $a^m=e_m$?

Answer (score 1):

This is easily seen by noting that an inner product is defined by $<x,y>=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ny_n$.

So for your question we can note $a^m=<a^m,e_n>\to<0,e_n>=0$ converges weakly, noting that $a^m\in H$ and $(e_n) $ an orthonormal sequence, for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then to show that it isn't strongly convergent we let $n,p\in\mathbb{N}$ for $n\neq p$ then we have $||e_n-e_p||^2=<e_n,e_n>+<e_p,e_p>-<e_p,e_n>-<e_n,e_p> =2$, noting that $e_n,e_p$ are othogonal.

Then if you need to show it converges weakly you should apply Bessel's inequality and apply the vanishing test.

Comment: OK, I got it. Then $(e_n)$ is not Cauchy and also not convergent... but why $a^m$ is not strongly convergent?

Comment: We note that we are able to take a basis in $H$ such that we can apply the G-S orthogonalisation procedure to get an othornormal basis v. We then normalise this to get $u_i=\dfrac{v_i}{||v_i||}$. Then we are able to write $a^m$ as linear combinations of $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$. Then the result follows by applying similar to the above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $(e_n)_n$ is an orthonormal set in $H$.

The answer is no. Consider $a^m = me_m$. We have $a^m_n = m\delta_{mn} \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. However, $(a^m)_m$ is not even a bounded sequence.

---

However, there is this result:

> Let $(e_n)_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. Let $(a_m)_m$ be a bounded sequence in $H$ such that there exists $a \in H$ with $\langle a_m, e_n\rangle \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} \langle a, e_n\rangle$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $(a_m)_m$ converges weakly to $a$.